# Hibernate Jpa CriteriaBuilder joins a Enum value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm developing a project in Spring boot 3 and i have an issue with Hibernete "criteriaBuilder" to querying a "@ElementCollection" with an enum Authority.

```java
    // UserEntity.class
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Authority.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "t_user_authorities")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Authority> authorities;
```

In my Enum

```java
public enum Authority{
   CAN_POST
}
```

In the JpaSpecification

```java
  ...
  Join<Authority, User> authorityUserJoin = root.join("authorities"); // Wanna join the Authority here
  return criteriaBuilder.like(
            criteriaBuilder.lower(authorityUserJoin.get("authorities")), // If it was Entity, 'd be "authority" as property here
            '%'+value.toLowerCase()+'%'
  );
```

Helps

Comment: As error: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Basic paths cannot be dereferenced